# how to create table and insert data inside it but if there is table already the same name just insert data and do not create table anymore

Tags: php, mysql, sql

// new question

update to this question :

reason for asking this question

i want to create a button in the nav-bar which value is view transaction.
and i want to create specific table for each customer to easily search its transaction.

as for your comments i got an idea, i will just create 1 table for all customers, use $_SESSION to save and know who order something. for the current user to view his transaction history i will also use $_SESSION to view all his transaction. the problem is im not sure how to do that.

// old question

im creating an online ordering system and if the customer order it will save record to mysql database. if the customer is new ofcourse it doesn't have table specific for him so the system should create table and insert data into the table. but if the customer is old customer and already have a table specific for him, the system dont have to create a table, it will just insert record inside it.

example:

currently login customer is john  base of $_SESSION and he is new customer.
john order, but because he is a new customer the system should create a table for john and insert record in the table.

then next time john order, the system should not create table anymore instead, just insert record in the table of john

can you pls help me do this :)

Comment: Your data structure is totally broken.  You should not be creating a separate table for every user.

Comment: I would agree. The schema is wrong. Have a customer table related to a purchases/ordered table

Comment: @GordonLinoff im using mysql server with the of xampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: I would suggest looking at this schema for your problemhere]

Keep entities separate and save having to create a new customer table every time.

Alternatively check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ed32/3

Comment: how should i put it in codings, example the current login user is john with the company of abc, if john order something, the system will save the record with the table of customer that has a column of user, company name, item, date of order. what i want to do is when john want to see his transaction record hi will just click view transaction then it will show all his transaction record. so how should i put it in codings

Comment: Check the fiddle I provided as a starting point to figure out the select statement you would use.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can use [`IF NOT EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS your_table_name ...;

INSERT INTO your_table_name ...
```

With SQL Server:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('your_table_name', 'U') IS NULL
  CREATE TABLE your_table_name ...;

INSERT INTO your_table_name ...;
```

**Warning:**

Creating table per user is bad practise. Rethink your approach and make one table.

From [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Cre_tbl):

> CREATE TABLE @tbl
>
> The desire here is to create a table of which the name is determined
>   at run-time.
>
> If we just look at the arguments against using dynamic SQL in stored
>   procedures, few of them are really applicable here. If a stored
>   procedure has a static CREATE TABLE in it, the user who runs the
>   procedure must have permissions to create tables, so dynamic SQL will
>   not change anything. Plan caching obviously has nothing to do with it.
>   Etc.
>
> Nevertheless: Why? Why would you want to do this? **If you are creating
>   tables on the fly in your application, you have missed some
>   fundamentals about database design. In a relational database, the set
>   of tables and columns are supposed to be constant.** They may change
>   with the installation of new versions, but not during run-time.

Comment: Your answer is quite reasonable and doesn't deserve a downvote.